# Отправка переменной методом POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Есть форма с несколькими полями и

```
<input value="Оставить отзыв" type="submit"/>
```

Нажимаю на кнопку и все отправляется в переменную POST.
Также существует переменная javascript - никак не могу понять как мне ее отправить в POST при нажатии на кнопку "Оставить отзыв". Пробовал так

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
//$.post('/reviews/#leave-review', {'index_id':'1111'})
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'/reviews/#leave-review'
    , type:'POST'
    , 'a':id_review
    , success: function(response) {

    }
});

return true; });
```

Переменная никак не хочет появляться в POST.

Comment: 'a' неправильно, в ajax() есть параметр data для отправки данных http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (смотри Examples)

Comment: сделайте hidden input в форме с именем 'a' и с нжным id в value. Оно и отправится, раз форма отправляется

Comment: была такая идея, она работает, но так нельзя.

Comment: @votanko почему нельзя? один из очень даже разумных ходов, добавлять невидимые поля с хеш-данными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем как что-то использовать надо почитать и по изучать примеры. Сразу с головы не нужно писать того, чего ещё не знаете.

Одна из ссылок на офф. документацию по jQuery.ajax ([ссылка из комментария @Jean-Claude](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

Чтобы передавать параметры в скрипты с помощью `ajax` нужно добавить опцию `data`, которая должна быть объектом с набором полей, нужных вам.

**Например:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url:'/reviews/#leave-review'
    , type:'POST'
    , data: {
          a: id_review
        , someMyArray: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        , someMyObject: {a: 5, b: 7}
    }
    , success: function(response) {
        // вернувшийся результат хранится в response
    }
});
```

Кстати не совсем понятно откуда берется переменная `id_review`. Т.к. она не объявлена.

На сервере переменные будут доступны как:

```
$_POST['a']
$_POST['someMyArray']
$_POST['someMyObject']
```

Comment: $_POST же устарел? спортивнее $_REQUEST, не?

Comment: @Jean-Claude ну `$_REQUEST` хранит как `$_POST` данные так и `$_GET` данные, для простоты можно использовать и `$_REQUEST`, но я всегда контролирую, то что мне приходит, и знать с чем именно ты работаешь тоже важно (с гетом или постом)

Comment: Все равно в POST не появляется

Comment: @votanko ну, уже проблема на стороне сервера, откуда вы знаете что он не появляется, что вы делаете для этого

Comment: $.post('/reviews', {'index_id':'1111'}) - тоже не заработало

Comment: var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @votanko И где  именно вы это проверяете? что возвращает запрос в `Network`?

Comment: Дела, после нажатия на кнопку происходит перезагрузка страницы, и код записи переменной не успевает сработать - ну мне так кажется.

Comment: @votanko ну да, страница перезагружается потому что у вас стоит `return true`. Вы уж выбирайте, либо передавайте все данные с помощью аякса, либо все с помощью обычной отправки. И вы так и не объяснили что же вы хотите получить

Comment: думал, что есть такая возможность - буду искать другой путь.

Comment: @votanko ты бы написал в вопросе, итог того что ты хочешь получить, тебе бы точно подсказали. А так вопрос был лишь в том, как отправить переменную =)

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 'someValue';

Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url : 'services/DeleteAdminResource',
                    method : "POST",
                    params : {
                        versionId : value
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: У тебя ajax от ExtJs он не подходит для jQuery